# Perl Error: invalid argument while opening the file

Tags: perl

I am new in perl. I tried to execute below mentioned program:

I am trying to open a file and read the contents from the file.

```
$FILE=open(FILE,"\\10.82.71.28\Testing501\Test_Folder\834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms");
 if($FILE)
  {
   print "The file: $FILE has opened successfully";
  }
 else
{
  die "There is an error while opening the file :$!\n";
}

while($record=<FILE>)
{
  print $record;
}

close(FILE);
```

But while executing the program, I am facing an error:

There is an error while opening the file :invalid argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you execute

```
print "\\10.82.71.28\Testing501\Test_Folder\834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms";
```

You get

```
Unrecognized escape \T passed through at a.pl line 1.
Unrecognized escape \T passed through at a.pl line 1.
Unrecognized escape \8 passed through at a.pl line 1.
\10.82.71.28Testing501Test_Folder834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms
```

(You do use `use strict; use warnings;`, right?)

You want code to produce the following string:

```
\\10.82.71.28\Testing501\Test_Folder\834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms
```

As you can see above, the following obviously does not produce the desired string:

```
"\\10.82.71.28\Testing501\Test_Folder\834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms"
```

You could use the following:

```
"\\\\10.82.71.28\\Testing501\\Test_Folder\\834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms"
```

Comment: Why does everybody always use double quotes? What is wrong with `'\\10.82.71.28\Testing501\Test_Folder\834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms'` ?

Comment: @reinierpost, Because it's wrong? At a minimum, you'd need `'\\\10.82.71.28\Te...'`, though I'd use `'\\\\10.82.71.28\\Te...'` to avoid the very mistake you just made.

Comment: @reinierpost, If you're afraid of backslashes, you could use `'//10.82.71.28/Te...'`. Windows accepts both slashes equally.

Comment: Hmmm ... indeed ... I stand corrected ... the `\\` is special even in single-quoted strings.

Comment: @reinierpost, Yeah, to allow `'can\'t'`

Answer (score 3):

Use a `q` literal to escape the back slash like this

```
$filepath = q{\\\10.82.71.28\Testing501\Test_Folder\834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms};

open my $FILE, '<', "$filepath" or die "path: $!"
while($record = <$FILE>) {
---
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
open my $file, '<', 'path' or die "path: $!"
while($record = <$file>) ...
```

Bare file handles are very old fashioned, and using the lexically scoped file handle is considered good practice.  For one thing, the file will be closed when the variable goes out of scope.  Also, the 3 argument form of open is really the only form that is considered respectable these days.  There is really no reason to use any other form.

Answer (score 1):

You've already accepted an answer, but you can always use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

```
$FILE=open(FILE,"//10.82.71.28/Testing501/Test_Folder/834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms");
```

By the way, the standard Perl way is to use the `or`:

```
open(FILE,"//10.82.71.28/Testing501/Test_Folder/834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms") 
     or die qq(...);
```

And, it is preferred to use the three-parameter form, and use a scalar variable for the file handle. It makes it easier to pass the file as a subroutine argument:

```
my $file_name = '//10.82.71.28/Testing501/Test_Folder/834_KMS_FACE_834A.mms';
open my $fh, "<", $file_name 
   or die qq(Couldn't open the file $file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when git.exe used the file.
It can be really access denied in disguise.